# Either reason for or reason of

Tags: prepositions

Which should be used in the following sentence either **of** or **for**

> The commission set-up to submit a report about the reasons **for/ of** the fall in educational standards could not complete its work even after two years.

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary or similar resource? [This might help you](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/reason). (There are other issues with the sentence you quoted FYI)

Answer (score 1):

### For : shows reason/purpose/utility/duration of time

- A school **for** studying history.
- I answered **for** him.
- It's time **for** us to go.

### of : shows a link/belonging/relation

- I met a friend **of** Mary's.
- A panel **of** experts.
- You had plenty **of** time

Try these:

Sam has been taking care ___ her ___ nearly a year now.

> Sam has been taking care **of** her **for** nearly a year now.

Did Harry think ___ her that way?

> Did Harry think **of** her that way?

He wants one ___ his own.

> He wants one **of** his own.

### Answer

The commission set-up to submit a report about the reasons **for** the fall in educational standards could not complete its work even after two years.

> Here, **for** could be used if the report submitted concerns about the reason behind the fall in educational standards

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If the commission was set up to inquire into why educational standards had fallen it would be inquiring into the **reasons for** the fall. Other possibilities are "reasons behind the fall" and "reasons why educational standards fell". If the commission explained why its work was not completed its explanation would show the **reasons of** the commission for taking so long.

The words "reasons of" need to relate to a person or body, but instead of a person or body your sentence has "the fall in educational standards", and this does not fit.